# local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need get data from my form and treat them

```
def parsurl(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DomainForm(request.POST)
        context = { 'form': form, }
        if form.is_valid():
            r = form.cleaned_data.get('url_text')
            masall =parser_d(r)
            for mas1 in masall:
                try:
                    Events.objects.create(events_title=mas1[1], events_text = mas1[2],events_img = mas1[0], events_is_pars=1, events_seourl = "132")
                except:
                    print ("lololo")

    else:
        form = DomainForm()

    return render_to_response(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Exception Value:

```
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `context` in the `if request.method == 'POST'` branch, but not in the `else` branch. Therefore you get an error for `GET` requests.

You could fix it by moving the line outside of the if statement as follows:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
       ...
    else:
       ...
    context = {'form': form}
```

Comment: may be you and me started writing the answer at same time and you posted first. Now it seems the answers are same. So should I delete my answer?

Comment: mb u know, why i get Template-loader postmortem Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using engine : django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/ziberon/econom/ecosite/templates/<WSGIRequest: GET '/parser/'> (Source does not exist) django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/ziberon/econom/ecenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/temp‌​lates/<WSGIRequest: GET '/parser/'> (Source does not exist)

Comment: The error is because you are calling `render_to_response` incorrectly. It would be better to use `render` instead: `return render_to_response(request, 'form.html', context)`

Comment: @cjahangir looks like I typed a little bit faster than you this time ;) it's up to you whether to delete your answer.